# Navigation to other page using User Control

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

How can we navigate to other page on click on button in user control in windows store app? I tried by making a new frame object and calling navigate method, but no luck till yet.
thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860919/windows-8-usercontrol-frame-object-navigation & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758375/windows-8-user-control-navigation-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Frame` is a `ContentControl` that hosts the pages. If you want to navigate back and forth between pages you need to use a single `Frame` control. The default one is created in the `App` class in the default Visual Studio templates. You can save the instance reference of that `Frame` like by having a static property on the `App` class like: `public static Frame RootFrame { get; private set; }` and then set it where it is constructed - `App.RootFrame = new Frame()`. Then you can navigate simply by calling `App.RootFrame.Navigate()`.

Comment: can we navigate with in a page placing another frame inside grid and navigate to another user control or subpage

Comment: You can navigate to a `Page` in a `Frame` - that's what they are used for. You can also nest Frames within Frames.